# two condition for where Clause in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want execute a sql query with my php code but it is wrong and I don't know what is my problem!

```
$end_type = $executed[end_type];
$start_type = $executed[start_type];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `wants` WHERE ((`car`=? AND $start_type=? AND $end_type=?) OR (`car`=? AND $start_type=? AND $end_type='all'))";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(1, $executed[car]);
$query->bindValue(2, $executed[start_place]);
$query->bindValue(3, $executed[end_place]);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchall();
sendmsg($user_id, $results);
```

`sendmsg` is my massage sender function and it don't return any array even an empty array!
why? what in my solution?

Comment: any errorrs? use `$con->error` for fetching error and echo it.

Comment: Your code, in its current form, does not store or even dump the value returned by `sendmsg()`. Does the execution reach that function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here seems to be that you have five `?` placeholders in your prepared statement, but are only binding *three* values.  There might be some way to recycle binding values in PHP, but in this case I would rephrase your query as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM wants
WHERE car = ? AND start_type = ? AND end_type IN (?, 'all');
```

Updated PHP code:

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wants WHERE car = ? AND start_type = ? AND end_type IN (?, 'all')";
$query = $con->prepare($sql);
$query->bindValue(1, $executed[car]);
$query->bindValue(2, $executed[start_place]);
$query->bindValue(3, $executed[end_place]);
$query->execute();
$results = $query->fetchall();
```